# Need to hide $0.00 & replace by text 'Free Shipping' on checkout page if shipping method is free shipping

Tags: magento2

I need to hide $0.00 & replace by text 'Free Shipping' on checkout page if shipping method is free shipping

[image]

Comment: Have you tried hiding it with css?

Comment: I updated my question I think hiding with css will not work as i need to replace it by 'Free shipping'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override core price.js for shipping method into your theme.

path : `/vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price.js`

Replace below code :

```
    /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */

define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils'
], function (Component, quote, priceUtils) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Tax/checkout/shipping_method/price'
        },
        isDisplayShippingPriceExclTax: window.checkoutConfig.isDisplayShippingPriceExclTax,
        isDisplayShippingBothPrices: window.checkoutConfig.isDisplayShippingBothPrices,

        /**
         * @param {Object} item
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        isPriceEqual: function (item) {
            return item['price_excl_tax'] != item['price_incl_tax']; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
        },

        /**
         * @param {*} price
         * @return {*|String}
         */
        getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
            //todo add format data
            if (price === 0) {
                return "Free Shipping";
            }
            return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is working only change the file path (/vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price.js)

Comment: 1 more thing how can I hide free Shipping title which is shown by shipping method