# Magento 2 custom shipping method set default shipping price as text which 0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, shipping-methods

is it possible to set default shipping price as text in my custom shipping method
look like

```
$method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $shippingPrice = 'my text';
            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $result->append($method);
```

Comment: As per magento stander you can not set text in price. can you share what do you want to achieve to set text in price?

Comment: i have custom shipping method when go to checkout default shipping price is 0 when customer entered address than by address it's calculate rate so first time instead of 0 set to By Distance

i also try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277422/need-to-hide-0-00-replace-by-text-free-shipping-on-checkout-page-if-shippin
but it replace all shipping price where found 0 but i want just my custom shipping method

Comment: so you can add condition if selected shipping method is this then display text

Comment: You can get shipping method using `window.checkoutConfig.selectedShippingMethod`